# Chrome拡張のoptions.jsが発火しない

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

[公式ドキュメント](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options)に従って以下のようなコードを書いたのですが、白紙のページが表示されます。

`alert('a')//test`も動かないのでDOMContentLoadedイベント自体起きてないようです。なお、options.htmlとoptions.jsは同じフォルダに置いてます。

また、これに限らずoptions.jsをデバッグする方法はあるでしょうか？

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>W2UI Demo: grid-17</title>
    <script src="library/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/w2ui-1.5.rc1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=library/jquery-3.5.1.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function load(){
    alert('a')//test
    $('#grid').w2grid({ 
        name: 'grid', 
        show: { 
            toolbar: true,
            footer: true,
            toolbarAdd: true,
            toolbarDelete: true,
            toolbarSave: false,
            toolbarEdit: true
        },
        columns: [                
            { field: 'url', caption: 'URL', size: '45%', sortable: true},
            { field: 'title', caption: 'Title', size: '45%', sortable: true },
            { field: 'day_of_the_week', caption: 'Day', size: '120px'},
            { field: 'interval', caption: 'Interval', size: '120px', sortable: true }
        ],
        onAdd: function (event) {
            w2alert('add');
        },
        onEdit: function (event) {
            w2alert('edit');
        },
        onDelete: function (event) {
            console.log('delete has default behavior');
        },
        records: [
            { url: 'twitter.com', title: 'Twitter', day_of_the_week: 'Mon', interval: '7' },
           
        ]
    })
} 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いろいろ実験したところ、埋め込み形式で`options.html`を開いても`DOMContentLoaded`イベントはちゃんと発生することがわかりました。ただし、`alert()`など一部のメソッドは使えなくなるようです。
`manifest.json`に以下のように書き新しいタブを開く方式に設定すると、`alert()`なども実行されるようになりました。

```js
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
```

また、拡張機能の詳細画面から`background.js`と同じようにデバッグできることがわかりました。

**P.S.**
w2uiというjavascriptでグリッド表示できるライブラリがありますが、Chrome extensionの`options.html`では（メソッドがインラインに記述されるため）以下のエラーが出て使えません。

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 0):

manifest.jsonに、

```
{
    "name": "My extension",

    // (略)...

    "options_page": "options.html",

    // (略)...
}
```

を書き、options.htmlのheadタグの中に、

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="options.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

options.jsを指定します。

あと

```
alert('a')//test
```

は、

```
alert('a'); //test
```

セミコロンを行末(コメントの手前)に付けないと動かないと思います。

Comment: manifest.jsonで"open_in_tab": trueにしたらalert('a')は実行されるようになりました。w2uiがうまく表示されないのはそのままですがこれはw2ui自体の問題のようです

Comment: alertが実行されたということで、optionsが使えるようになったようで良かったです。w2uiは、optionsに組み込む前に通常のページでうまく動かす方法を理解した上でoptionsに組み込むとうまく行くと思います。

Comment: w2uiは選択などの動作をすると（起動関数がインラインに書かれているため）"Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."というエラーが出て使えませんでした。

Comment: 新しい疑問が出てきたときは、別の質問として聞いてください。1つの質問にその質問への回答という形にすることで探しやすくすることが出来ます。この問題が解決したら、解決済みを押してもらえるとよりわかりやすくなります。よろしくお願いします。